# Specify interface when adding default gateway via SIOCADDRT

Tags: c, linux, routes, ioctl

I'm trying to set my machine's default gateway via `SIOCADDRT` and `ioctl()`. I found the following snippet online that works just fine:

```
int fd = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP );

struct rtentry route;
memset( &route, 0, sizeof( route ) );

struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)&route.rt_gateway;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "10.0.2.2" );

addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_dst;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_genmask;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

// TODO Add the interface name to the request
route.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
route.rt_metric = 0;

int rc = ioctl( fd, SIOCADDRT, &route );
// [...]
```

Now for the `TODO` in this snippet... How do you actually specify which interface to use? When I execute this code, it seems to default to `eth0` on my machine (which is my only interface). The definition of the `rt_entry` struct in the `route.h` header is the following (Also available [here](http://kerneldox.com/kdox-linux/d0/df5/structrtentry.html)):

```
   /* This structure gets passed by the SIOCADDRT and SIOCDELRT calls. */
   struct rtentry {
    unsigned long   rt_pad1;
    struct sockaddr rt_dst;     /* target address       */
    struct sockaddr rt_gateway; /* gateway addr (RTF_GATEWAY)   */
    struct sockaddr rt_genmask; /* target network mask (IP) */
    unsigned short  rt_flags;
    short       rt_pad2;
    unsigned long   rt_pad3;
    void        *rt_pad4;
    short       rt_metric;  /* +1 for binary compatibility! */
    char *rt_dev;   /* forcing the device at add    */
    unsigned long   rt_mtu;     /* per route MTU/Window     */
    #define rt_mss  rt_mtu          /* Compatibility :-(            */
    unsigned long   rt_window;  /* Window clamping      */
    unsigned short  rt_irtt;    /* Initial RTT          */
};
```

thx for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there are two fields you can use to specify the interface:

> struct ifnet *rt_ifp;
>
> struct ifaddr *rt_ifa;
>
> These two fields represent the “answer”, as it were, to the question posed by a route
> lookup; that is, they name the interface and interface address to be
> used in sending a packet to the destination or set of destinations
> which this route represents.

Update:
There's an `rt_dev` field in the sturct, I think you can set it to the interface name:

```
char ifname[] = "eth1";
rtentry.rt_dev = ifname;
```

Comment: I've seen those flags in online specs too, however my version of the headers does not have these fields. I'll edit my question.

Comment: mine doesn't either, I think it's `rt_dev` not sure how to set it though, probably an interface index, can you try that ?

Comment: it's actually a `char *` so I think it's the interface name

Comment: huh, must've overlooked that one, gonna try it now